# Adding data of an unknown type to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby seems like a language that would be especially well suited to solving this problem, but I'm not finding an elegant way to do it.  What I want is a method that will accept a value and add it to a hash like so, with specific requirements for how it is added if the key already exists:

Adding 'foo' to :key1

```
{:key1 => 'foo'}
```

Adding 'bar' to :key1

```
{:key1=> 'foobar'}
```

Adding ['foo'] to :key2

```
{:key2 = ['foo']}
```

Adding ['bar'] to :key2

```
{:key2 => [['foo'], ['bar']]
```

Adding {:k1 => 'foo'} to :key3

```
{:key3 => {:k1 => 'foo'}}
```

Adding {:k2 => 'bar'} to :key3

```
{:key3 => {:k1 => 'foo', :k2 => 'bar'}}
```

Right now I can do this but it looks sloppy and not like idiomatic Ruby.  What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Not that I'm exactly sure what you are trying to do here but why isn't the array part `{:key2 => ['foo', 'bar']}`?

Comment: If you just defined #+ on Hash to do #merge, you could just use that. def add(h, k, v); h[k] ? h[k] += v : h[k] = v; end

Comment: It wasn't a good example, but I'm jsut showing that it has to be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it more Ruby-like you might want to extend the Hash class to provide this kind of functionality across the board, or make your own subclass for this specific purpose. For instance:

```
class FancyHash < Hash
  def add(key, value)
    case (self[key])
    when nil
      self[key] = value
    when Array
      self[key] = [ self[key], value ]
    when Hash
      self[key].merge!(value)
    else
      raise "Adding value to unsupported #{self[key].class} structure"
    end
  end
end
```

This will depend on your exact interpretation of what "adding" means, as your examples do seem somewhat simplistic and don't address what happens when you add a hash to a pre-existing array, among other things.

The idea is that you define a handler that accommodates as many possibilities as reasonable and throw an exception if you can't manage.

Comment: The examples might be simplistic, but are all that my requirements need.  Btw it is off topic, but if you are extending built in classes, where would this go in a Rails project?

Comment: You'd generally put them in your lib directory.

Comment: Actually ended up putting it in my config/initializers directory.  Need it to load before any of my code loads right?

Comment: `config/initializers` is a great place for little "extension" scripts, but if they grow to more than a few dozen lines, make the initializer a hook to load the full `lib/` hosted library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to utilize the polymorphic feature of oop, you might want to do:

```
class Object; def add_value v; v end end
class String; def add_value v; self+v end end  # or concat(v) for destructive
class Array; def add_value v; [self, v] end end # or replace([self.dup, v]) for destructive
class Hash; def add_value v; merge(v) end end  # or merge!(v) for destructive

class Hash
  def add k, v; self[k] = self[k].add_value(v) end
end
```